# How to get access to an object in the list from other class?

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I have a list of objects in an array list in some class:

```
public class Customer implements barber.barberapp.crud {
private String[] data = {"id", "imie", "nazwisko", "email", "tel"};

public static List<Customer> getClients(){
    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();

    Customer c1 = new Customer("001", "Adam", "Nowak", "an@wp.pl","123");
    list.add(c1);

    list.get(0).data[0] = "999"; //checking if accessing object works correctly

    return list;
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to access the list in other class like that, I get an error "cannot resolve symbol get".

```
public class CustomerListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Customer> list = Customer.getClients();
    list.get(0).data[0] = "999" //error here
}
```

Edit: getClients method returns List < Customer > now, but the problem is still here.

Comment: Your "data" is private you can't  access it outside your class unless you implement getters and setters...Anyway the design of your class seems a bit messed up

Comment: Are you perhaps forgetting to put a semicolon at the end of the line `list.get(0).data[0] = "999"`?

Comment: changed it to public, but it didn't make error disappear. semicolon is not the issue either. intelliJ doesn't even accept "get" when I write list.get(0)

Comment: Can you provide MCVE? Including imports. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, unless it's an instance variable, needs to go inside a method. So after implementing a getter (`getData()`) in your `Customer` class, try something like this:

```
public class CustomerListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Customer> list = Customer.getClients();
    public void yourMethod(){
        list.get(0).getData()[0] = "999";
    }
}
```

Inside the Customer class

```
public String[] getData(){
     return data;
}
```

That said you might want to redesign your class since it looks a bit odd and note that you should provide an explicit constructor for the Customer class since this is how you create an instance of Customer

```
Customer c1 = new Customer("001", "Adam", "Nowak", "an@wp.pl","123");
```

Hope that helped.